# Stop video player logs flutter

Tags: android, flutter, exoplayer

I am using the flutter video_player package in my app. It is continuously printing logs. How can I disable it? I have already tried the solution from here, but it does not work

[Preventing ExoPlayer used via video_player in Flutter from spamming the logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62151254/preventing-exoplayer-used-via-video-player-in-flutter-from-spamming-the-logs/62152411#62152411)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any official soultion yet.
You might want to try filtering the console like this

- vscode: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/59579#issuecomment-872731355
- Android studio: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55965761/8253662

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there appears no easy solution for this for now, but for the *nix users, this following trick might be a handy alternative.

```sh
# ripgrep  
flutter run --hot --track-widget-creation | rg -v "Codec|Audio|Video|Buffer|Exo"

# awk 
flutter run --hot --track-widget-creation | awk  '!/Codec|Audio|Video|Buffer|Exo/ {print}'
```