# How to get rid of video player logging details in flutter?

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, terminal, flutter-video-player

I am using https://pub.dev/packages/video_player for the video playback in my flutter app and flutter_bloc to manage the state of the application. When I load the video player screen, I get thousands to unwanted log messages in my VS Code terminal, which eventually makes debugging pretty hard as I need to observe the state of the app. Following links aren't helping: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/59579 [Stop video player logs flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65748780/stop-video-player-logs-flutter)
[image: Here's the screenshot of my vs code terminal]

Comment: They are emulator/Android debug messages, and there isn't really a good way to disable them. You will just have to filter them out.

Comment: Yes, I have. But still, these messages are so annoying and counter productive

Answer (score 0):

My Solution is temporary,but it worth
if you run in debug mode you could apply filter to your terminal to ignore the prints
hope help you