# What causes ColorUtils: expected specified color aspects

Tags: android, logcat, google-ads-api, android-sdk-tools

Recently my application started spamming logs with the following set of messages

```
W/ColorUtils: expected specified color aspects (0:0:0:0)
D/ReflectedParamUpdater: extent() != 1 for single value type: algo.buffers.max-count.values
D/ReflectedParamUpdater: extent() != 1 for single value type: output.subscribed-indices.values
D/ReflectedParamUpdater: extent() != 1 for single value type: input.buffers.allocator-ids.values
D/ReflectedParamUpdater: extent() != 1 for single value type: output.buffers.allocator-ids.values
D/ReflectedParamUpdater: extent() != 1 for single value type: algo.buffers.allocator-ids.values
D/ReflectedParamUpdater: extent() != 1 for single value type: output.buffers.pool-ids.values
D/ReflectedParamUpdater: extent() != 1 for single value type: algo.buffers.pool-ids.values
```

I can't see the "expected specified color aspects" in the sources my IDE has downloaded or by Googling and I have struggled to identify what triggers this, since the log is quickly overwhelmed by these messages

The only reference I found which could be related is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62151254/preventing-exoplayer-used-via-video-player-in-flutter-from-spamming-the-logs) but I do not use exoplayer. The only thing which may be using videos is the Google Ads SDK.

Does anyone know what the root cause is for this spam? If it's in ads, is there a way to disable it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It was indeed the Google Ads SDK that causes this spam.

The only way to disable it (at time of writing) is to disable video ads, or remove the SDK

Comment: Downvoted two years after writing, but the answer remains correct, sadly